Change strategy Momentum TradingView PineScript v. 5
How can I change the code so that only long positions are opened and closed? I don't want to go short here.
//@version=5
strategy("Momentum Strategy", overlay=true)
length = input(12)
price = close
momentum(seria, length) =>
    mom = seria - seria[length]
    mom
mom0 = momentum(price, length)
mom1 = momentum( mom0, 1)
if (mom0 > 0 and mom1 > 0)
    strategy.entry("MomLE", strategy.long, stop=high+syminfo.mintick, comment="MomLE")
else
    strategy.cancel("MomLE")
if (mom0 < 0 and mom1 < 0)
    strategy.entry("MomSE", strategy.short, stop=low-syminfo.mintick, comment="MomSE")
else
    strategy.cancel("MomSE")
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)

I changed the code, but it didn't work

do not use strategy.entry("MomSE", strategy.short ... then, and close the MomLE  position instead
